# ReactNative Issue: FBReactNativeSpec Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native, macos

I'm using a MacBook Air and i have issue running my native react project on my macOS.

**Specs and Info:**

- M1 chip
- MacOS Ventura 13.2.1
- Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)
- node v16.10.0
- nvm v0.39.1

When I try to run the app in terminal by typing yarn start or npm start then pressing run on the xcode after building i am getting this error:
`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

**What I did so far:**

- delete pod > delete node_module > reinstall module > pod install > clean build > run
- removed other node version and reinstall 16.10.0 > did the step one again > run
- deleted the FBreactnative > did the step one again > run
- did the step one > added engine set to 16.10.0 at package.json > run
- added NODE_BINARY config at xcode env with path `/Users/mashwishi/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node`
- also tried using `sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node` for alias

[image]

Note: only ios have the problem, i was able to run the android project